# Excel 2010 formatting issue

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two cells, both are using the *General* formatting type, and both contain the same Conditional Formatting rule (data bar of minimum type: Number (0) to maximum type: Number (20).

Both cells contain the exact same formula, but with their own respective lookup credentials:

=IF(**C13**="",VLOOKUP(B13,Equipment!$A$5:$AD$1000,4,0),VLOOKUP(**B13**,Equipment!$A$5:$AD$1000,4,0)+VLOOKUP(**C13**,Equipment!$A$5:$AD$1000,4,0))

**AND**

=IF(**K13**="",VLOOKUP(J13,Equipment!$A$5:$AD$1000,4,0),VLOOKUP(**J13**,Equipment!$A$5:$AD$1000,4,0)+VLOOKUP(**K13**,Equipment!$A$5:$AD$1000,4,0))

The formatting issue I'm having:

The first case is not formatting in the Conditional Formatting, and it's aligning the text to the *left*. The second case is formatting in the Conditional Formatting, and it's aligning the text to the (default) *right*.

What's the problem with this?

Comment: What range does the conditional format apply to? Can you post a screenshot of the problem? It's a bit hard to picture.

Comment: Teylyn: The range is =$B$16:$Y$16, but I removed this formatting as a test, and added the formatting to ONLY cell B16, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: pnuts: =$B$16:$Y$16 is the range that have data bars. Most of them work. If I uncheck Show Bar Only, the value in the trouble cell shows 3, but the value in the working cell disappears. For Min/Max Type/Value in CF Rules Manager, the values are set from 0 (Min) to 20 (Max). =$B$16:$Y$16 is also the applies to range, but if I delete the conditional formatting and recreate it using only the trouble cell (B16), it still does not format the way I'm trying to format it.

Comment: pnuts continue: All of the VLOOKUP fields that are being looked up, contain a single digit integer, with their respective cells formatted to text. This works in respect to the cell J16, for example.

Comment: I just now realized what I think is the oddity. The non-working formatted fields all contain the IF empty cell value.

Apparently the cells that are just looking up a VLOOKUP aren't formatting, but the ones that are ADDING two VLOOKUPs are.

Comment: Interesting that if you add two text formatted numbers, Excel treats it as numerical, but if you do not, Excel treats it as text.

Seems like a contradiction. Now I just have to find out how to change greater than 600 cells to General, so that the conditional formatting functions. Only way I know to do that is to select each cell individually and highlight the formula window and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been unsuitable formatting (text rather than numeric) of some of the data being fed to formulae used for determining the extents of the data bars which therefore did not perform as expected. It seems the solution is a simple as converting from text to numeric some cells that display as digits.

Although it seems there are many such cells it is quick and easy to do so all at one time if taking advantage of error checking (if necessary, turned on in Excel Options, Formulas, Error Checking, Enable background error checking which normally gives warning where appropriate by way of a small green triangle in the top left hand corner of relevant cells).

Select the rage required, starting with the indication in the top left-most cell and an exclamation mark should appear which may be clicked to select *Convert to Number*.